# Unpack the tuples in an array for graph visualisation

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array generated from PLSRegression with number of components set to 2

```
(array([[ 0.48362376,  1.15908429],
       [-2.47132438,  0.44989534],
       [-2.60893728,  0.5381059 ],
       [-2.53155766,  0.3469423 ],
       [-1.89554596,  0.73211665]]))
```

I want to get the X_1 and X_2 coordinates to plot a 2 dimensional scatter plot. So in this case, the X_1 and X_2 coordinates would be

```
X_1 = [0.48362376,-2.47132438,-2.60893728,-2.53155766,-1.89554596]

X_2 = [1.15908429,  0.44989534, 0.5381059,0.3469423,0.73211665]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your array be `x`. Then, you can use indexing as follows:

```
x_1 = x[:, 0]
x_2 = x[:, 1]
```

`x[:, 0]` means, you take the every row (`:`) and the first column (`0`). Thus, you receive an array with the elements of the first column.

Remember, with `x[1, 0]`, you take the element from the second row and the first column. Instead of using colon in place of a specific number, you simply select "all" elements in the respective dimension.